# Sublime/Python: executing a php script via shell in a path that changes

Tags: python, shell, sublimetext3

I'm currently using an open-source SCSS compiler, however, every time I make changes to a scss file, I have to run the compiler manually to compile the output. So, to combat this, I edited a Sublime package that allows people to run commands on file saves and it goes like this:

```
class CommandOnSave(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
def on_post_save(self, view):
    settings = view.settings()
    current_file = view.file_name()

    if current_file.endswith("scss"):
        subprocess.call("php path/to/phpscript", shell=True)
```

Now, the only issue is that one folder in the path changes with every project, and it would be ideal if there was some way to dynamically execute the php script so I don't have to have a settings file with multiple paths in it to accomplish this.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do this without a lot of server overload? The php script always resides four directories down from the scss file. I've tried ../../../.. but that doesn't work (obviously) since the command isn't looking for the file from the current file's path.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you edit your question and be more specific about your operating system and the SCSS compiler in question?

Comment: You could `import os` and afterwards try something like `php_script = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(view.file_name()), "../../../../path/to/script.php"))` and `subprocess.call("php " + php_script, shell=True)`

Comment: This actually worked ^